# Unable to create Horizontal Tab dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was following this website to create Horizontal Tabs dynamically using Jquery

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

I have create a fiddle for this of my code

http://jsfiddle.net/CMKVh/1/

Could anybody please let me know the efficient way of creating Horizontal tab which must be split in two lines

I tried with following code

```
function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
    var categoryArr = JSON.parse(categories);
    var htmlbuild =$('<ul>');
    for(var i=0;i<categoryArr.categories.length;i++)
    {
        var name = categoryArr.categories[i].name;
        htmlbuild.append('<li><a href="'+name+'">name</a></li>');
    }
    var htmlbuild =$('</ul>');
    $("#tabs").append(htmlbuild);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your code is related to jQuery UI tabs, your `var htmlbuild =$('</ul>');` line is overwriting everything previously put in `htmlbuild`, and I don't understand what you mean by 'Horizontal tab which must be split in two lines'

Comment: Please see this site http://www.menucool.com/jquery-tabs#view3 , 2 lines means i need 4 items on one line and another 4 items in another line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var categories= '{"categories":[{"name":"Snacks"},{"name":"One"},{"name":"Two"},{"name":"Three"},{"name":"Four"},{"name":"Five"},{"name":"Six"},{"name":"Seven"}]}'; 
createhorizontaltab(categories);
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
var categoryArr = JSON.parse(categories);
var htmlbuild =$('<ul>');
for(var i=0;i<categoryArr.categories.length;i++)
{
 var name = categoryArr.categories[i].name;
 htmlbuild.append('<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a></li>');
}
$("#tabs").append(htmlbuild);
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/CMKVh/2/